# How I can add a audio trim on audio file which is stored on FileManager in swift iOS?

Tags: swift, audio, trim

With AVFoundation can we edit(trim) an audio which was earlier recorded and stored on the file manager by simply giving starting and ending time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem.

```
 func trimSelectedAudio(){ 

    let name = browseData.name!
    if let asset = AVURLAsset(url: getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(tfTitle.text!).m4a")) as? AVAsset{
        exportAsset(asset, fileName: name)
    }
}

func exportAsset(_ asset: AVAsset, fileName:String){
    let trimmedSoundFileUrl = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(tfTitle.text!)_trimmed.m4a")
            print("Saving to \(trimmedSoundFileUrl.absoluteString)")


    if let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A){
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4a
        exporter.outputURL = trimmedSoundFileUrl

        let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)
        if duration < 5.0{
            print("Audio is not song long")
            return
        }
        let startTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(selectAudioRange.selectedMinValue), 1)
        let stopTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(selectAudioRange.selectedMaxValue), 1)
        exporter.timeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime)

        exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            print("export complete \(exporter.status)")

            switch exporter.status {
            case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:

                if let e = exporter.error {
                    print("export failed \(e)")
                }

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                print("export cancelled \(String(describing: exporter.error))")
            default:
                print("export complete")
                self.deleteFileAlreadyPresent()
                // change core data data here
            }
        })
    } else{
        print("cannot create AVAssetExportSession for asset \(asset)")
    }
}

func deleteFileAlreadyPresent(){
    let PresentAudioUrl = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(previousAudioName).m4a")
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: PresentAudioUrl.path){
                print("Sound exists, removing \(PresentAudioUrl.path)")
                do{
                    if try PresentAudioUrl.checkResourceIsReachable(){
                        print("is reachable")
                        self.deleteRecordingFile(audioName: "\(previousAudioName).m4a")
                        self.saveTrimmedData()
                    }
                   // try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: trimmedSoundFileUrl.absoluteString)
                } catch{
                    print("Could not remove \(PresentAudioUrl.absoluteString)")
                }
            }
}

func saveTrimmedData(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.browseData.image = (self.imgToSave.image?.jpeg!)!
        self.browseData.note = self.tfNotes.text
         self.browseData.name = "\(self.tfTitle.text!)_trimmed"



    do{
        try self.context.save()
        self.goToParentVC()

    } catch let error as NSError{
        print("Could not save \(error) \(error.userInfo)")
    }

         }
}
```

Comment: it is incomplete code and not working, there are too many variables which do not have any information like `browseData`, `context` etc ..